# How to trigger event on change of element content.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following element

```
<div id="upload_area">
    Images      
</div>
```

If the content of  `<div id="upload_area">` changes(like from images to photo),I want to trigger some event.The content of   `<div id="upload_area">` is getting values dynamically.
how can i do this?

Comment: What would make it change?  You generally would trigger the event in the javascript that does the change...

Comment: How the `<div id="upload_area"></div>` change its content?

Comment: @Newbie The content of   `<div id="upload_area">` is getting values dynamically.

Comment: @Muk: It might be getting values dynamically but that doesn't happen by magic, there's code being executed to retrieve and add that content - what is that code?

Comment: what is the event you want to fire

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function after your code to change its content. If you wanted to, for example, trigger a `click` event handler bound on that `<div>`, you'd do:

```
$('#upload_area').trigger('click');
```